# Pure vs Impure methods ES6 classes. Should I pass the values around or should I store them in the object

Tags: java, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am 100% sure this topic was discussed before but I didn't manage to give a proper search on google so here I am.

Usually when I am writing classes I have a specific methods which does something and inside it I structure each step like this:

```
  Class MyClass {
    ......


    mainMethod() {
      this.runValidation();
      const val1 = this.method1();
      const val2 = this.method2();
      const val3 = this.method3(val1, val2);
      const val4 = this.methid4(val1, val3);
      ......
      return finalResult
    }
}
```

and I chose to store in the current object only some specific values. Maybe it is better this way, or maybe I am using it in more places and it is easier to access, it depends.

My question is what would be a better practice. The one I just showed you above, or the one like in the following piece of code:

```
  Class MyClass {
    ......


    mainMethod() {
      this.runValidation();
      this.method1()
      this.method2()
      this.method3()
      ......
      return this.finalResult
    }
}
```

where I am constantly changing the properties of the current object?

Comment: While this is an interesting question, it will depend on the situation and the opinion of the developer.

Comment: I agree, but I would like to hear different opinions for this to see what people have in their mind.

Comment: Which do you think is easier to read?